# Android App unavailable for download in Isle of Man

Tags: google-play-store

I'm having the same problem as the [BBC iPlayer app for Android](http://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/tv/tablet/android-isle-of-man-channel) where our Android app is not available for download in the Isle of Man, from the Google Play store.

As IoM is part of the UK, it should be available already as the UK is a selected territory.

Does anyone know of a workaround apart from our users travelling to the UK and downloading it?

Comment: And apart from that, *Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher* are [off topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I read that some internet providers on the Isle of Mann route their signal through Ireland disallowing the download of the software by IP address.

I'd recommended checking to see if you can download it through WiFi or finding an APK of the latest version and just installing it.

EDIT: Just provide the APK direct to them